# collectionView Images: Change Height Dynamically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In the scenario, images are downloading and showing into `collectionview`, and it is working fine, but images are displaying in different ways. I have shown all the images and they all possess the same height and the same width. If an image is small then it will take the default image height and width. I have shown all the images are same height and width displayed in properly.

[image]

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "storeCell", for: indexPath) as? EShoppingStoreCollectionViewCell
        cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground.cgColor
        cell?.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

        let urlData = storeDictionary?[indexPath.item]["logo"] as? String
        cell?.storeImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        cell?.storeImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        let frame = CGRect(x: (cell?.storeImageView.frame.width)!/2 - 30, y: (cell?.storeImageView.frame.height)! - 30, width: 60, height: 60)

        if urlData != nil {
            let url = URL(string: urlData!)
            cell?.storeImageView.sd_setImage(with: url!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named:""), options: [SDWebImageOptions.continueInBackground, SDWebImageOptions.lowPriority, SDWebImageOptions.refreshCached, SDWebImageOptions.handleCookies, SDWebImageOptions.retryFailed]) { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Failed: \(String(describing: error))")
                } else {
                    print("Success")
                }
            }
        }
    return cell!
}
```

how can I set all images same size

Comment: What do you mean by same size? `UIImageView` must have same size in all of the cells right?

Comment: @PGDev I have make all images hight and width same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of `image` is not in your hand. It is what it is received from the API. So it is better to use a right resolution image with `contentMode` set to `scaleAspectFit` instead of stretching it.

Still if you want same size in the display, try changing contentMode of imageView to `scaleAspectFill` or `scaleToFill`

```
cell?.storeImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
```

This will definitely stretch the images but all the images that you see in display will cover the size of `imageView`.

You can also choose another way that'll make your UI look better - set a `backgroundColor` of `imageView` and set its `contentMode` to `scaleAspectFit`.